# Understanding sequence of operations with dependency in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

Referring https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/operation, I am having Playground setup as -

```
class myOperation1 : Operation {
    override func main() {
        print("op1 working....")
    }
}

class myOperation2 : Operation {
    override func main() {
        print("op2 working....")
    }
}

let op1 = myOperation1()
let op2 = myOperation2()

op1.completionBlock = {
    print("op1 finished")
}

op2.completionBlock = {
    print("op2 finished")
}

op2.addDependency(op1)

let opsQue = OperationQueue()
opsQue.addOperation(op1)
opsQue.addOperation(op2)
```

And console log is -

```
op1 working....
op2 working....
op1 finished
op2 finished
```

Shouldn't we expect output as result of dependency? -

```
op1 working....
op1 finished
op2 working....
op2 finished
```

Same result with using - `opsQue.addOperations([op1, op2], waitUntilFinished: true)`

```
op1 working....
op2 working....
op1 finished
op2 finished
```

Comment: To avoid code ordering, you can use `opsQue.addOperations([op1, op2], waitUntilFinished: true)
`

Comment: and try out with dependency and without dependency

Comment: @WeiJay: Maybe I should not observe this behavior in Playground, in actual project it should work as expected

Comment: @BaSha no, checking it on playground should reflects the same output, if you want to re-test it, just tap on the blue arrow button (execute playground), that will rerun the code and you would see different result at each run :)

Comment: @AhmadF: Exactly, with same dependency I see different results :)

Comment: Completion blocks for Operations run asynchronously, usually on a random secondary thread. Thus, it's totally "random" where the output of `print` gets placed in the console relative to the output produced by `print` of the worker thread. Note that several `print` functions called from different threads _may_ get serialised.
This means, all what you are experiencing is _expected_.

Answer (score 6):

In fact, *I can't determine what's exactly  the mystery of why your code does not work as it should*, but I figured out 3 workarounds to achieve what are you trying to:

If you are expecting that the output should *always* be:

```
op1 working....
op1 finished
op2 working....
op2 finished
```

then:

**1-** You might want to add the second operation to the queue in the completion block of the first one, as follows:

```
class myOperation1 : Operation {
    override func main() {
        print("op1 working....")
    }
}

class myOperation2 : Operation {
    override func main() {
        print("op2 working....")
    }
}

let opsQue = OperationQueue()

let op1 = myOperation1()

op1.completionBlock = {
    print("op1 finished")

    opsQue.addOperation(op2)
}

let op2 = myOperation2()

op2.completionBlock = {
    print("op2 finished")
}

opsQue.addOperation(op1)
```

**2-** Setting [maxConcurrentOperationCount](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/operationqueue/1414982-maxconcurrentoperationcount) operation queue to 1, as follows:

```
class myOperation1 : Operation {
    override func main() {
        print("op1 working....")
    }
}

class myOperation2 : Operation {
    override func main() {
        print("op2 working....")
    }
}

let op1 = myOperation1()
let op2 = myOperation2()

op1.completionBlock = {
    print("op1 finished")
}

op2.completionBlock = {
    print("op2 finished")
}

op2.addDependency(op1)

let opsQue = OperationQueue()
// setting maxConcurrentOperationCount to 1
opsQue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
opsQue.addOperation(op1)
opsQue.addOperation(op2)
```

**3-** Calling [waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/operationqueue/1407971-waituntilalloperationsarefinishe) after adding the first operation to the queue, as follows:

```
let opsQue = OperationQueue()
opsQue.addOperation(op1)
opsQue.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()
opsQue.addOperation(op2)
```

---

btw, for a non-complex task, I prefer to use GCDs.

Hope this helped.

Comment: So what if there are 3 operations, so i need to add opsQue.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished() after each time i addOperation

Answer (score 3):

The completion block is called after the dependancy operation starts, but it doesn't mean that the first operation didn't end.

As quoted in @Xoronis's answer:

> The exact execution context for your completion block is not guaranteed but is typically a secondary thread. Therefore, you should not use this block to do any work that requires a very specific execution context.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/1408085-completionblock

Take a look at this example:

```
class myOperation1 : Operation {
    override func main() {
        print("op1 working....")
        for i in 1...10 {
            print("\(i)")
        }
    }
}

class myOperation2 : Operation {
    override func main() {
        print("op2 working....")
    }
}

let op1 = myOperation1()
let op2 = myOperation2()

op1.completionBlock = {
    print("op1 completed")
}

op2.completionBlock = {
    print("op2 completed")
}

op2.addDependency(op1)

let opsQue = OperationQueue()
opsQue.addOperations([op1, op2], waitUntilFinished: true)
```

will result in

```
op1 working....
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
op2 working....
op1 completed
op2 completed
```

The first operation does end before starting its dependancy, but the completion block is called after the dependancy already started.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation for the completion block (emphasis mine),

> The exact execution context for your completion block is **not guaranteed** but is typically a secondary thread. Therefore, you should not use this block to do any work that requires a very specific execution context. 
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/1408085-completionblock

So, in a more realistic sense of when you want to know exactly when an operation is finished, you'd do something more like this:

```
class myOperation1 : Operation {
    override func main() {
        print("op1 working....")
        //Do things
        print("op1 finished")
    }
}

class myOperation2 : Operation {
    override func main() {
        print("op2 working....")
        //Do things
        print("op2 finished")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set maxConcurrentOperationCount to 1 of the opeation queue than it will work as expected.

```
     let operationQueue = OperationQueue()
     operationqueue?.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1

    let operation1 = Operation()
    let operation2 = Operation()

    operation1.completionBlock = {
        print("operation1 finished")
    }

    operation2.completionBlock = {
        print("operation2 finished")
    }

    operation2.addDependency(operation1)

    operationQueue.addOperation(operation1)
    operationQueue.addOperation(operation2)
```

Answer (score 1):

By specifying the dependency, it is guaranteed that `op2` gets scheduled after `op1` completes, but not necessarily that `op2` gets scheduled after the completion handler of `op1` has finished.

Comment: I think statement contradicts - The receiver is not considered ready to execute until all of its dependent operations have finished executing 
(https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/operation/1412859-adddependency)

Comment: @BaSha: what do you mean? Where do you see a contradiction? `addDependency` adds a dependency on the operation, not on the completion handler...

Answer (score 0):

initializing the operationQueue  suspended will give you what you want.

```
let queue = OperationQueue()
let downloadOp = Operation()
let resizeOp = Operation()
downloadOp.dependency(resizeOp)
queue.isSuspended = true
queue.addOperation(downloadOp)
queue.addOperation(resizeOp)
queue.isSuspended = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested to use isSuspended. The main queue could be operated after the completion of each operation.

```html
class OperationChain: Operation {
    var mainQ: OperationQueue?
    var text: String?
    
    init(with name: String, by mainqueue:OperationQueue){
        self.text = name
        self.mainQ = mainqueue
    }
    
    override func main() {
        self.mainQ!.isSuspended = true
        print(text!)
        sleep(5)
        self.mainQ!.isSuspended = false
    }
}

let oq = OperationQueue()
oq.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1

let q1 = OperationChain(with: "Operation.main.q1", by: oq)
print("q1")

q1.completionBlock = {
    //sleep(5)
    q1.mainQ!.isSuspended = true
    var i = 0
    repeat {
        i = i + 1
    } while i < 100
    print("q1.completionBlock") 
    q1.mainQ!.isSuspended = false
}

oq.addOperations([q1], waitUntilFinished: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use adapter to make sure the order of the execution:

```
op1 working....
op1 finished
op2 working....
op2 finished
```

Here is the modified code:

```
import Foundation

class myOperation1 : Operation {
    override func main() {
        print("op1 working....")
    }
}

class myOperation2 : Operation {
    override func main() {
        print("op2 working....")
    }
}

let op1 = myOperation1()
let op2 = myOperation2()

op1.completionBlock = {
    print("op1 finished")
}

op2.completionBlock = {
    print("op2 finished")
}

let adapter = BlockOperation(block: {})

adapter.addDependency(op1)
op2.addDependency(adapter)

let opsQue = OperationQueue()
opsQue.addOperation(op1)
opsQue.addOperation(op2)
opsQue.addOperation(adapter)
```